# SSH command within a script terminates prematurely

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, ssh, netcat

From myhost.mydomain.com, I start a nc listener. Then login to another host to start a netcat push to my host:

```
nc -l 9999 > data.gz &
ssh repo.mydomain.com "cat /path/to/file.gz | nc myhost.mydomain.com 9999"
```

These two commands are part of a script. Only 32K bytes are sent to the host and the ssh command terminates, the nc listener gets an EOF and it terminates as well.

When I run the ssh command on the command line (i.e. not as part of the script) on myhost.mydomain.com the complete file is downloaded. What's going on?

Comment: Note: You can achieve the same with `ssh repo.mydomain.com "cat /path/to/file.gz" > data.gz` Maybe your script is more complex but maybe someone overlooked the simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is something else that happens in your script which causes this effect. For example, if you run the second command in the background as well and terminate the script, your OS might kill the background commands during script cleanup.

Also look for `set -o pipebreak` which terminates all the commands in a pipeline when one of them returns with != 0.

On a second note, the approach looks overly complex to me. Try to reduce it to

```
ssh repo.mydomain.com "cat /path/to/file.gz" > data.gz
```

(`ssh` connects stdout of the remote with the local). It's more clear when you write it like this:

```
ssh > data.gz repo.mydomain.com "cat /path/to/file.gz"
```

That way, you can get rid of `nc`. As far as I know, `nc` is synchronous, so the second invocation (which sends the data) should only return after all the data has been sent and flushed.

Comment: I can't stream all the data via ssh (or scp it) because of the low compute capacity available on the sender. It is faster (at least 4-5x in my case) to simply netcat it. There's no pipebreak as well.

I tweaked the second command to be:
ssh repo.mydomain.com "nc myhost.mydomain.com 9999 < /path/to/file.gz". Same observation. Only that this time 4K bytes were sent. This behavior is independent of the file

Comment: The 4KB is an indication that `nc` could only fill the send buffer (which is 4KB) once before it was stopped. Try to wrap `nc` in a script which runs `date 1>&2` (connects stdout with stderr) before and after the command just to see how long it runs. Also try `nc -v`; that might give you more information how many bytes are written/received. As for speed: The speedup probably happens because `ssh` encrypts the connection. See https://serverfault.com/questions/116875/how-can-i-disable-encryption-on-openssh for ways to optimize